# How to get all files in folder using FTP in WinInet?

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet

How can I download all files from a specific folder on an FTP server using WinInet?

Answer (score 1):

Per the WinInet documentation:

[FTP Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/ftp-sessions)

> ...
>
> **Navigation is provided by the `FtpGetCurrentDirectory` and `FtpSetCurrentDirectory` functions.** These functions utilize the session handle created by a previous call to `InternetConnect` to determine which directory the application is currently in, or to change to a different subdirectory.
>
> **Directory enumeration is performed by using the `FtpFindFirstFile` and `InternetFindNextFile` functions.** `FtpFindFirstFile` uses the session handle created by `InternetConnect` to find the first file that matches the given search criteria and returns a handle to continue the directory enumeration. `InternetFindNextFile` uses the handle returned by `FtpFindFirstFile` to return the next file that matches the original search criteria. The application should continue to call `InternetFindNextFile` until there are no more files left in the directory.
>
> ...
>
> **To download or get files, the application can use either `FtpGetFile` or `FtpOpenFile` (with `InternetReadFile`).** `FtpGetFile` is used to retrieve a file from an FTP server and store it locally, while `FtpOpenFile` and `InternetReadFile` can be used to control where the downloaded information is going (for example, the application could display the information in an edit box).
>
> ...

More detailed information, and code examples, of each of these actions are provided in the documentation.

Note that you cannot perform other FTP commands while in the middle of a directory enumeration. So, you will need to enumerate the directory in full first, storing the desired file names into a temporary list, and then afterwards you can enumerate that list downloading each file as needed.